# Flask test gives response 200 when expecting 302

Tags: unit-testing, flask

I'm trying to figure out why my Flask test is not working correctly. I'm testing a view function '/register' that successfully redirects to a dashboard when I run the site on localhost.

My test for this behavior fails and instead feeds back a 200 response.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/casey/python/storm/project/tests/test_views.py", line 30, in test_register_user
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 302)
AssertionError: 200 != 302
```

My test and view code are below:

```
# tests/helpers.py

from unittest import TestCase
from views import app

class PhotogTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = app.test_client()
        self.client.testing = True
        app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

# tests/test_views.py
from helpers import PhotogTestCase

class TestRegister(PhotogTestCase):
    """Test our registration view."""

    def test_register_user(self):
        # Ensure page loads with correct text
        resp = self.client.get('/register')
        assert 'Register for an Account' in resp.data

        # Ensure that valid fields result in success.
        resp = self.client.post('/register', {
            'email': 'c@gmail.com',
            'password': 'woot1LoveCookies!',
            'password_again': 'woot1LoveCookies!'
        }, follow_redirects=True)
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 302)

# views.py
import uuid
from forms import RegistrationForm
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, \
    request, url_for, flash, current_app, abort
from flask.ext.stormpath import StormpathManager, login_required, \
    groups_required, user, User
from stormpath.error import Error as StormpathError
from flask.ext.login import login_user

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    """
    Register a new user with Stormpath.
    """
    form = RegistrationForm()

    # If we received a POST request with valid information, we'll continue
    # processing.
    if form.validate_on_submit():

        data = {}
        # Attempt to create the user's account on Stormpath.
        try:
            # email and password
            data['email'] = request.form['email']
            data['password'] = request.form['password']

            # given_name and surname are required fields
            data['given_name'] = 'Anonymous'
            data['surname'] = 'Anonymous'

            # create a tenant ID
            tenant_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
            data['custom_data'] = {
                'tenant_id': tenant_id,
                'site_admin': True
            }

            # Create the user account on Stormpath.  If this fails, an
            # exception will be raised.
            account = User.create(**data)

            # create a new stormpath group
            directory = stormpath_manager.application.default_account_store_mapping.account_store
            tenant_group = directory.groups.create({
                'name': tenant_id,
                'description': data['email']
            })

            # assign new user to the newly created group
            account.add_group(tenant_group)
            account.add_group('site_admin')

            # If we're able to successfully create the user's account,
            # we'll log the user in (creating a secure session using
            # Flask-Login), then redirect the user to the
            # STORMPATH_REDIRECT_URL setting.
            login_user(account, remember=True)

            # redirect to dashboard
            redirect_url = app.config['STORMPATH_REDIRECT_URL']
            return redirect(redirect_url)

        except StormpathError as err:
            flash(err.message.get('message'))

    return render_template(
        'account/register.html',
        form=form,
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When making the request, you set `follow_redirects=True`, so naturally you see the final page rather than the intermediate redirect.  Set `follow_redirects=False` instead.